# Mock TCP response with WireMock in c#

Tags: c#, mocking, integration-testing, wiremock

I am doing some integration tests and one of the components is creating a tcp connection with a 3rd party server, writes the data on a network stream and then it reads the response. Is there a way to mock that server with WireMock?

I've done so far this code:

```
        WireMockServer server = WireMockServer.Start();

        using (var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", server.Ports.First()))
        {
            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("bytes sent");
            }
        }
```

But how to simulate a response on this stream based on the bytes that I've sent?

Answer (score 0):

WireMock.Net does only support mocking HTTP calls. TCP, UCP and WebSockets are not yet supported.